# neo4j webadmin page not coming up

Tags: neo4j

When I hit the url below

http://ec2-54-214-168-109.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:7474/

I am getting the following message

The connection has timed out

The server at ec2-54-214-168-109.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com is taking too long to respond.

The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few
    moments.
  If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer's network
    connection.
  If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure
    that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.

In neo4j-server.properties I have opened the webserver address to allow connections from any IP address using the line below

```
org.neo4j.server.webserver.address=0.0.0.0
```

I would appreciate any pointers towards resolution

Comment: Did you open port 7474 for (at least) your IP in the security group settings?

Comment: Yes here are the rules defined for the security group

Comment: Ports Protocol Source default
22 tcp 0.0.0.0/0 
80 tcp 0.0.0.0/0 
7474 tcp 0.0.0.0/0

Comment: can you ssh to the machine and use `netstat --tcp --listen --numeric` to check which ports are used by programs?

Comment: Executing the command produced the following

Comment: tcp        0      0 :::7474                     :::*                        LISTEN

Comment: I have removed all other entries from the post except 7474 I also noticed that 80 was not being used

Comment: Never mind 80 won't come since I queried for tcp. Still I am at a loss to find why webadmin page won't come

Comment: Can you get something from `curl http://localhost:7474/webadmin` on that machine, so we know the local instance is up and the problem is somewhere in the external IP access config?

Comment: curl http://localhost:7474/webadmin did not return any thing

Comment: However the command below did work                                     curl http://ec2-54-214-168-109.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:7474/webadmin/

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

        <head>

                <link rel="icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" href="img/favicon.ico">

                <script data-main="js/webadmin" src="js/require.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
                <!--[if IE]><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/excanvas.js"></script><![endif]-->

                <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" />

                <title>Neo4j Monitoring and Management Tool</title>

        </head>

        <body>

        </body>
</html>